# Encrypt and Decrypt Bank Account information

Tags: asp.net

I have bankAccountnumber and routing number stored in SQL Server.

How I can encrypt those information most secure way?

What datatype I should use?

I want to use Hashcode with salt but I do not know how to decrypt?

SQL Server table

```
Salt    varbinary(250)  not null
bankAccountnumber binary(16)    not null
```

Code

For encryption below code work but I do not know how to decrypt bankaccount number. I do not know I am using right datatype.

```
public void CreateNewAccount(AccountManagementView userAccount)
{
            byte[] salt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hereissalt");
            byte[] hashedbankaccnumber = CreateSaltedField(salt, userAccount.bankAccountnumber);

            BuildInsertQueryForTable("User")
                .SetColumnToValue("ID", Guid.NewGuid())
                .SetColumnToValue("EmailAddress", userAccount.EmailAddress)
                .SetColumnToValue("Salt", salt)
                .SetColumnToValue("bankAccountnumber", hashedbankaccnumber )
                .ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is function generating encryption key

```
private static byte[] CreateSaltedField(byte[] salt, string bankAccountnumber)
{
    return new HMACMD5(salt).ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bankAccountnumber));
}
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: frankly, if you need to ask, you probably shouldn't be dealing with this sort of thing.

Comment: Hahaha then how will it be secure?? You are leaving everything open  :P

Comment: It would be more secure with a more-experienced developer working on it.

Comment: *Hey, yeah, **great idea**. Let's post an answer here then we can hack into their bank!*. But in all seriousness if you need to ask this question you shouldn't *really* be working on this project.

Comment: Gotta wonder who upvoted this and for what reason: http://puu.sh/dwcSs/47b2bb5498.png

Comment: I don't think Bank Account Number is sensetive data. It's just a serial number but you must hash password and then binary compare that.

Comment: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use Hashcode with salt but I do not know how to decrypt?

You cannot use Hash with Salt such as SHAXXX. It is one way encryption, and it is used for encrypting password.

You might want to look at [TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is quite strong.

***FYI:*** Normally, Bank knows what the requirement is, and the kind of requirements comes from upper-level. Please consult with your supervisor.